# IPtables: Forward port to another host is not working

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, linux-networking

I am trying out something so this is my test setup:

**Setup:**

- I have AWS VPC with a public and private subnet.
- I have a host in public subnet with a public IP address (say **Host A**)
- I have a host in private subnet running nginx on port 80 (Say **host B** with IP address `10.0.1.132` )

**What I want to do**

I want to access the Webserver on Host B from Internet by visiting Host A.

**How**

I setup IP forwarding parameter in `systctl.conf` on host A and then put below `iptables` rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.132:80
```

**Issue:**

It is not working and I am not able to open the WebPage when I visit host A on port 80

**Other info (with respect to AWS VPC Security Group):**

- I have `port 80` incoming access on `host A` from `0.0.0.0/0`
- I have `port 80` outgoing access on `host A` to `10.0.1.0/24`
- I have incoming `port 80` access on `host B` from `host A`

Here is the kernel info:

```
# sysctl  -p | grep forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Also, I am able to telnet on port 80 from Host A to host B on port 80. So this certifies that my AWS security group is working as expected.

I think I am going wrong on `IPtables` part. Could help me figure out what is wrong in above setup.

Answer (score 1):

Do you realize that private host should …

- … have default route pointing back to the router?
- … be SNATed so that its replies would go back?

Comment: +1. Working on it. Will update with my outcome soon.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I am going wrong on IPtables part. Could help me figure out what is wrong in above setup.

Correct, The traffic will be getting through the Amazon Security Group, but then getting blocked by IPTables. You need a forward rule that will accept the NAT'd traffic:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp -d 10.0.1.132:80 -j ACCEPT
```

Note that -A may not be correct, you might need to -I (insert) then provide a number after "FORWARD" which represents where in your FORWARD chain you want to insert the rule. (ie before any DROPs) You can list your FORWARD chain with

```
iptables -L FORWARD -n --line-numbers
```

Comment: When I run this command on Host A, I get `iptables v1.4.7: host/network '10.0.1.132:80'` not found` error.

Comment: I tried `iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp -d 10.0.1.132 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` instead and the command worked. working further now.

Comment: Glad you figured it. Please accept the answer.

Comment: My issue still exists. I am working on it. I meant the command ran successfully after I altered it a bit.