# AWS VPC + IPtables + NAT: Port Forwarding is not working

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, linux-networking, amazon-vpc

Yesterday, I posted a question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/570093/iptables-forward-port-to-another-host-is-not-working) but I think was not clear enough in my words. BTW, This question is not a duplicate.

I have AWS VPC Setup as below.

[image]

**GOAL/PROBLEM**: SSH to Server A from internet. And It is not working.

Server A is in private subnet and hence I want to enable iptables NATing on the my NAT instance so that I can ssh to SErver A directly from internet

I am following [this](http://www.whiteboardcoder.com/2012/12/amazon-aws-vpc-iptables-and-nat-route.html) and [this](http://paulpodolny.blogspot.in/2013/03/port-forwarding-for-amazon-vpc.html)

I ran below command on NAT instance:

```
NAT# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.243:22
```

IP forwarding is enableed on NAT instance:

```
NAT# sysctl  -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

MASQUERADE is running on NAT instance:

```
NAT# iptables -t nat -vnL POSTROUTING
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 312 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  199 16466 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    10.0.0.0/16          0.0.0.0/0
```

AWS Security groups are configured fine to allow various access needed for this test case.

**Troubleshooting:**

I can telnet from NAT to Server A on port 22. So Access is good.

When I run `telnet 54.213.116.251 2222` on my laptop, I see below entry in tcpdump on NAT:

```
NAT# tcpdump -n -i eth0 dst 10.0.1.243 and port 22
09:59:13.738316 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.51709 > 10.0.1.243.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1868541786, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
09:59:16.737009 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.51709 > 10.0.1.243.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1868541786, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
09:59:22.775567 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.51709 > 10.0.1.243.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1868541786, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

So it means the iptables is routing the packets to `10.0.1.243`. (BTW, `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is  public ip address of my laptop)

But When I run tcpdump on Server A, I do not see anything coming from `10.0.0.54` which is the Internal/Private IP address of NAT (*And I think this is the problem*):

```
Server A# tcpdump  -n src 10.0.0.54
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
```

But if I telnet from NAT instance to Server A, I see good stuff in tcpdump on Server A(*This means, My overall `PREROUTING` Rule is not working as expected*):

```
Server A# tcpdump  -n src 10.0.0.54
05:01:47.500080 IP 10.0.0.54.44627 > 10.0.1.243.ssh: Flags [S], seq 2862522431, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3013083 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
05:01:47.501601 IP 10.0.0.54.44627 > 10.0.1.243.ssh: Flags [.], ack 760676524, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 3013083 ecr 12074896], length 0
05:01:47.535720 IP 10.0.0.54.44627 > 10.0.1.243.ssh: Flags [.], ack 22, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 3013092 ecr 12074928], length 0
```

**Conclusion:**

From tcpdump output on NAT, It seems that Iptables is forwarding my packets fine.

from TCP dump on Server A, I have good connectivity from NAT to Server A.

But in End-to-end, I am not able to connect to the server A from my laptop.

(*BTW, I know SSH tunnel and other good stuff. But I want only Iptables to help me with this.*)

Comment: Did you disable source/destination checking on your NAT instance?

Comment: What does it mean? How to check that? I searched the entire Iptables man page but is does not say thing about source/destination checking (unless I missed anything obvious.)

Comment: You have to do that in AWS web console (or CLI).  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck

Comment: Thanks. I find that it is already `Disabled` for the NAT instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, I Cracked it !!!!

On the NAT instance, I had to change below command:

From:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.0.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
```

To:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

And it WORKED!!!!

So, I will be creating a new question soon on ServerFault asking what are the advantages and disadvantages in using above two commands.

Comment: Man thanks in a million. Had the same problem, same.... Every step was in place... but this "-o eth0" was there as well. Removed it, worked like charm. Thanks in million.

Comment: The reason why it works is because the "-s 10.0.0.0/16" says to only translate packets with *source* ip 10.x.x.x.  I'm guessing your home laptop was on your home network and was coming from some external IP so the NAT was ignoring your laptop's requests.  Others may want to run "ip r" on the linux command line to see if eth0 is really the name of their ethernet device.  If not, change it to whatever your eth device is named (ex. ens192 or whatever).

Comment: Oh, also, I learned the above by reading the iptables man page.  It's really good and not a long read.  I highly recommend it.  Run "man iptables" from the command prompt to see it in all it's glory.

Answer (score 7):

- Make sure that you are allowing tcp port `2222` inboud from `0.0.0.0/0` on the security group for your nat box
- Make sure you have your VPC "Route Table" setup properly.
- At least two separate tables (one associated with the private subnet, one associated with the public subnet)
- Your `10.0.1.0` (private) subnet should have a route table rule like: Destination: `0.0.0.0/0`, Target: "Nat box"
- Your `10.0.0.0` (public) subnet should have a route table rule like: Destination: `0.0.0.0/0`, Target: "Internet gateway"
- Make sure you have Source/destination checking **disabled** on the NIC for your NAT box, no NATting fun without it. (I know you already have this but its *really* important, so including it for some future viewer)
- Make sure outbound packets know where to go:

  `iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --source 10.0.0.0/16 --destination 0.0.0.0/0 --jump MASQUERADE`
- Make sure inboud packets to `2222` get rerouted properly:

  `iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --protocol tcp --dport 2222 --jump DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.243:22`

Comment: Your every single suggestions are already in place. Thanks.

Comment: I updated it to show all the steps

Comment: Thanks. +1 for your efforts. Your `MASQUERADE` command is not helpful in my case. May be I am missing something. The Only `MASQUERADE` command that gets me flying is the the one I have mentioned in [my answer](http://serverfault.com/a/570630/114516).

Comment: This is all great advice except this won't work because you're only routing 10.x.x.x on in your first iptables command.  He wants to route anything coming from the internet.  See OP's own answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This posts helped me a lot in understanding AWS NAT. So I started to investigate what made `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE` it worked.

Well the answer I found the above statement is allowing the NAT box to source NAT the 'LAPTOP' IP to '10.0.0.54' while same time performing destination NAT to 10.0.1.243. At this time the private subnet box is ssh request coming from NAT device only. This command is actually decreasing the security of the private subnet server. It is recommended to use the below command to fine tune the private subnet access through ssh and NAT box as mentioned below;

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --source "INTERNET IP of the Laptop" --destination 10.0.1.243 --jump MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit safer:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 52.213.216.251 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.243:22
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.0.1.243 -j SNAT --to-source 52.213.216.251
```