# Apache Instance in Private Subnet not returning packets

Tags: nat, ping, packets, networking

How can we get the Apache instance in a private subnet to work?

**Configuration**
Public subnet with 1 NAT instance
Private subnet with 1 App instance

**Details**
 1. Masquerading is turned on NAT on via

```
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

2. PREROUTING is enabled via
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --port 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.10.102:80`
 3. Port forwarding is enabled in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
 4. Security group for both NAT & App (Would never keep these in production but
    purely to show all ports are open)

```
    Inbound All Traffic 0.0.0.0/0
    Outbound All Traffic 0.0.0.0/0
```

5. Network ACLs

```
    Inbound All Ports 0.0.0.0/0
    Outbound All Ports 0.0.0.0/0
```

6. Ping & wget work for external requests

```
    ping google.com
    wget google.com
```

7. Apache is listening on the App instance in the private subnet.

```
    netstat -tulpn
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
    tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

**Apache Traffic**
Public Requests to the Apache server on the private subnet does not work.

```
wget http://127.0.0.0.1/index.html   => success
# public IP requests
wget http://xxx.x.x.x/index.html   => failure
Connecting to xxx.x.x.x:80...      => hangs
```

From the NAT host terminal

```
sudo tcpdump -i any -n port 80
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-10-0-0-71
15:22:17.668089 IP 10.0.10.102.54033 > X.X.X.X.80: Flags [S], seq 848018267, win 26883, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 19553465 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:22:17.668111 IP 10.0.0.71.54033 > X.X.X.X.80: Flags [S], seq 848018267, win 26883, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 19553465 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

What do we need to do so Apache will work from the private subnet?

Comment: Is this AWS? If so, did you verify that forwarding is enabled in the kernel and that source/destination checking is disabled?

Comment: Are you masquerading on the NAT instance? This post might be useful http://serverfault.com/questions/570386/aws-vpc-iptables-nat-port-forwarding-is-not-working

Comment: @EEAA yes this is AWS.  Source/destination checking is disabled. Forwarding is enabled in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward. Is there somewhere else to check on the forwarding?

Comment: @Andrew `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`.  Ping does not work.  wget does though.

Comment: Correction: ping does work to external network -> ping google.com.  Ping fails to network public ip -> ping X.X.X.X fails

Comment: is apache listening on eth0?

Comment: on the App instance in the private subnet, Apache is listening on port 80.  It is not listening on the NAT instance.  I don't believe it should be, correct?

Comment: Do you have the needed rules on the NAT device in the filter table's FORWARD chain and the nat table's PREROUTING chain?

Comment: I will add above but this rule is enabled.  `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.10.102:80`.  Can you explain more about the FORWARD rule or anything that may be wrong with the PREROUTING given?

Comment: @MarkWagner Thank you.  Please submit an answer with FORWARD chain so I can award the bounty.  My default rules were to DROP forwarded traffic.